# I cant find odd or even in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

i.e "20200612", this program execute 2+2+0+1, all I want is 2+2+6+2 the sum of all even  numbers

```
(task.year.to_s +
 task.month.to_s +
 task.numberofemployer.to_s).split(//)
                            .map{|p|   p.to_i}
                            .select.each_with_index { |_, p| p.even? }.sum
```

Comment: Your code is unnecessarily verbose, but it *almost* works. Your only mistake is that [`each_with_index`](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.7.1/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_with_index) yields `|element, index|`, not `|index, element|`. So in that final line of your code, the variable `p` actually represents the **index**, not the element.

Comment: A few pointers for asking a good question on StackOverflow: (1) Try to write a more descriptive title. Perhaps "Summing the even digits in a string", rather than "I can't find odd or even". (2) Try to write a **minimal** code sample. (See; [mcve].) You didn't need to include that code about the `task.year.to_s + ...`, you could have simply written `"20200612".split(//)....` as this would have been shorter, simpler and totally reproducible. (3) Try not to add unnecessary tags. The crux of your question has got nothing to do with `ruby-on-rails`, so there's no need to tag it as such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In that case you have to remove the `each_with_index`, because you need to check if the current element is even, not the index of that element in `'20200612'.split(//)`:

```
'20200612'.chars.map(&:to_i).select(&:even?).sum
# 12
```

This is what happens if you use the yielded values from `each_with_index`:

```
[[2, 0], [0, 1], [2, 2], [0, 3], [0, 4], [6, 5], [1, 6], [2, 7]]
  even            even            even            even
```

You have the current element and its index, and you're checking if the index is even, that's why you get 2, 2, 0, 1

Comment: An alternative answer, just for fun: `"20200612".scan(/[2468]/).map(&:to_i).sum`

Comment: That's nice @TomLord, `sum(&:to_i)` if your Ruby version allows it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems every method of chars, map, select and sum, does an own loop, so, I think is too much, talking about accepted solution.

The ugly is that the below solution is Two lines, but only a loop, check with a benchmark:

```
@a = 0
'20200612'.gsub(/[2468]/) { |v| @a += v.to_i; ''}
# puts @a => 12
```

This another one, is faster too:

```
'20200612'.chars.inject(0) { |sum, v| v.to_i.even? ? sum + v.to_i : sum }
# 12
```

And this is another good way:

```
@a = 0
'20200612'.chars.each { |v| @a += v.to_i.even? ? v.to_i : 0 }
# puts @a => 12
```

In my tests, the last one is the fastest.